# Sublime paste code in specific file across multiple directories

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Let say I have 3 directories containing same file name like `style.css`.

Is there a copy/paste method in Sublime Text editor to paste code once at the end  of all css files (`style.css`) ?

```
 dir1
     style.css
  dir2
     style.css
  dic3
     sytle.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard *”Find in files…”* operation and regular expressions to do this.

1. Open the dialog (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Mac OS X, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> elsewhere)
2. Activate the *Regular expression* button on the left (by default it's labeled `.*`)
3. Put `\z` in the *Find* field, that will search the end of string
4. Optionally, specify file names in the *Where* field to limit the operation, e.g. `style.css`
5. Put `appended_text` in the *Replace field* (or `\nappended_text` to append the text into the next line)
6. Press the *Replace* button

Comment: clever solution :) is the `$1` necessary in the replacement when there are no capture groups in the regular expression?

Comment: also, `\Z` will potentially find multiple results per file, as it matches at the newlines before the end of the file. I recommend using `\z` instead, which matches only the very end of the file.

Comment: You're right, `$1` is not required. Updating the answer with both your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will try soon.

Comment: Can you please tell me is there a way to paste complete file in directories ?